# Apache poi setformula doesn't work With SE

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I'm trying ti set a formula in a XSSFCell With POI.

```
Cell.setFormula("SE(D87=0; ""; D80/D87)");
```

The error is:

> Name 'SE' is completely unknown in the current workbook.

Why?

Comment: Are you sure that formula isn't a typo? Only I don't recognise `SE` as a normal function name...

Comment: @Gagravarr  I don't understand... What is a typo?

Comment: Are you sure it should just be `SE` on it's own, and not something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to create an `IF` formula.  I found [this page](http://wwwhome.ewi.utwente.nl/~trieschn/excel/excel.html) about Excel formula translations into different languages, where I found that the English formula name `IF` translates to `SE` in a few languages.

I don't believe that Apache POI supports formula names in names other than English.  Try the English name.  You may or may not need to replace the semicolons with commas; I'm not sure if Apache POI takes that into account.

```
cell.setCellFormula("IF(D87=0, \"\", D80/D87)");
```