# POI Excel formula translated?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using German Excel 2007 and therefore the English formula are not evaluated automatically. In the German Excel I have no clue, where resp. how to get it working to evaluate English formulas.

So, I thought I am using the German ones, but this only throws a `FormulaParsException`. Setting the formula directly as cellvalue is obviously wrong, cause the content is not evaluated. I thought, perhaps I can turn off the evaluation resp. parsing, but no real success to it. I have seen, that I can write my own function, but to be honest, I wanna use an already built-in-function of Excel.

Can anybody give me a hint, how to use `COUNTIF` in German Excel? Resp. how to convince POI to accept `ZAEHLENWENN`?

Comment: I never had problems with German/English formulae. I always used the English expessions (SUM, COUNTIF etc) and `setFormula()` and the German Excel recognized it correctly.

Comment: Well, yeah after some trial and error I figured out that the problem relates to the function `ZAHLENWENNS` (for which the English `COUNTIFS` exits) is not recognized . So, I switch over to different calc (`SUMPRODUCT`) which works and is translated properly (within Excel). Thx for the hint anyway.

Comment: Check you're on a new enough copy of Apache POI - there have been quite a few more formula functions implemented of late

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253212/apache-poi-setformula-doest-work-with-se).

As stated in the answer, Apache POI doesn't support multiple languages, so you will have to use the English formulas to make it work.