# Java/Apache POI - Formula aren't setting on cell correctly

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I have a Java code where I create a new .xlsm file which I create mirroring the format of another empty .xlsm file. My problem is when I set a formula in a specific cell on this new .xlsm created. When I open the file, the cell display: #NAME?. But when I press enter key in the cell, the formula is displayed correctly. And when i get out, the formula works.

Why does this happen?

Java code is as below:

```
public static String main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection( 
         "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database" , 
         "user" , 
         "password"
      );

      Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from `table`");
      FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Folder1.xlsm"));
      XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(file)); 
      XSSFSheet spreadsheet = wb.getSheet("Planilha1");

      XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(1);
      XSSFCell cell;
      int i = 1;

      while(resultSet.next()) {
         row = spreadsheet.createRow(i);
         cell = row.createCell(1);
         cell.setCellValue("");
         cell = row.createCell(2);
         cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("column1"));
         i++;
      }

      XSSFRow linhacontador = spreadsheet.getRow(1);
       if (linhacontador == null) {
        linhacontador = spreadsheet.createRow(1);
       }

      XSSFCell colunacontador = linhacontador.getCell(34);
       if (colunacontador == null) {
        colunacontador = linhacontador.createCell(34);
       }

       colunacontador.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
       colunacontador.setCellFormula("CONT.SE(AH:AH, \"<>\")");

      CellRangeAddress range = new CellRangeAddress(1, i-1, 25, 25);
      spreadsheet.addMergedRegion(range);


      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\exceldatabase.xlsm"));
      wb.write(out);
      out.close();
      connect.close();

      return "Worksheet Done!";
   }
```

Apparently my problem is here:

```
   colunacontador.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
   colunacontador.setCellFormula("CONT.SE(AH:AH, \"<>\")");
```

Comment: Can you try the "english version" of the formula.. (COUNTIF)? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15254518/592355, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224631/poi-excel-formula-translated

Comment: Ok, i will try. Let me just a second

Comment: Actually, it works! I wrote COUNT.IF and doesn't work, when i remove the dot, works. Thanks @xerx593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it should be written in English. Like CONTSE going to be: COUNTIF. SOMA going to be SUM.. and so on. Just, search the formulas in english version and will works.